# How to handle exceptions with switch case

Tags: c#

Working on a project, new to c# here, and I'm trying to take care of unhanded exceptions. What I'm trying to do is give the user a helpful error message whenever they type something that isn't one of the choices and keep prompting them until they enter a valid response.

```
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
    //    bool userBool = false;
    //    while( userBool){
           
    //    }
    
        switch (Int32.Parse(input))
        {
            
            case 1:
                farm.AddGrazingField(new GrazingField());
                Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                break;
            case 2:
                farm.AddPlowedField(new PlowedField());
                Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                break;
            case 3:
                farm.AddNaturalField(new NaturalField());
                Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                break;
            case 4:
                farm.AddChickenHouse(new ChickenHouse());
                Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                break;
            case 5:
                farm.AddDuckHouse(new DuckHouse());
                Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

I know I could do this with a while loop and conditionals but havent been successful doing that with switch case.

Comment: You can use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) and check its return value before going into `switch/case`.

Comment: Are you talking about potential exceptions being thrown by `Int32.Parse(input)`.  It's best to parse user input using the `TryParse` methods - a user entering data in an incorrect format is hardly *exceptional*, it's expected.  Consider something like `if(!int.TryParse(input, out int inValue) || inValue < 1 || inValue > 5) {/*signal an error and prompt again */}`

Comment: There is a big difference between exception handling and error handling. Exceptions are things that (should) only happen in exceptional circumstances. Exceptions should be unexpected, like running out of hard drive space when writing a file. Errors are things that happen regularly and in expected ways, like bad user input. You should program to allow for errors. When you have exceptions you should handle specific exceptions in a graceful manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function to both read and also validate the input of the user:

```
int GetUserInput()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(input, out var value))
            return value;
    }
}
```

This function will not throw an exception if the user enters an invalid value. Instead it will prompt the user again. You can expand this to limit the range of the input that you allow and write descriptive error messages.

Comment: Consider passing minValue and maxValue into that function as parameters.  Then you can change the prompt to `$"Please enter a number between {minValue} and {maxValue}"`, and you can re-prompt if it's out of range.

Comment: @Flydog57: Good suggestion. I will leave that as an exercise to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score -1):

Please observe the below updates in your code.

```
      try
   
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your input in number form");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (Int32.Parse(input))
            {

                case 1:
                    farm.AddGrazingField(new GrazingField());
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    farm.AddPlowedField(new PlowedField());
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    farm.AddNaturalField(new NaturalField());
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    farm.AddChickenHouse(new ChickenHouse());
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    farm.AddDuckHouse(new DuckHouse());
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Facility has been added");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Can proovide more info to user to make sure he knows the input to be entered or options available to him
            Console.WriteLine("Please verify the input");
        }
        finally
        {
            //As it will get executed in case of exception also you can log some message or perform something here
        }
```

This is just the beginning. You can have your custom exceptions and use them for logging messages.

Comment: Catching exceptions that should have been avoided (by using `TryParse` rather than `Parse`) isn't much of a solution

Comment: There's a very specific exception that is raised when you get bad input in a `Try` method. If you are going to use exception handling then you should catch that specific exception. You should never catch `Exception`. But, as others have said, `TryParse` is the way to go to avoid exceptions in the first place.

Comment: TryParse is the best practice we follow. When I mentioned custom exception It meant to be specific. I mentioned a way to handle exceptions and yes this was just demo. There are lots of best practices and thinking goes in exception handling.